# Jenkins Scipted Pipeline: re-use same docker container in different stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following example

```
def plan() {
  def tasks = [:]

  tasks["Bootstrap"] = {
    stage ("Bootstrap"){
      node {
        sh 'echo bootstrap'
      }
    }
  }
  tasks["Platform"] = {
    stage ("Platform"){
      node {
        sh 'echo platorm'
      }
    }
  }

  parallel tasks
}

def apply() {
  def tasks = [:]

  tasks["Bootstrap"] = {
    stage ("Bootstrap"){
      node {
        sh 'echo bootstrap'
      }
    }
  }
  tasks["Platform"] = {
    stage ("Platform"){
      node {
        sh 'echo platorm'
      }
    }
  }

  parallel tasks
}
```

So in the plan stage both `Bootstrap` and `Platform` will need to use the same docker container but will produce different artifacts.

In the apply stage for both `Bootstrap` and `Platform`, I need to use the same docker container from `plan` in the `apply` so I can access those artifacts.

Is this possible?

Comment: it's tricky to use the same container when you're telling jenkins to give you different nodes for each parallel task. i'm not sure what you're trying to do (more information about the "why" is often helpful), but maybe you could use `stash` and `unstash` to make the artifacts you need available.

Comment: I have the same command that I'd like to run in a docker container that takes different arguments and generates different artifacts that need to be there during the apply stage. So I'd like run a container and store the artifact in the container to use it during the apply.